# Why variables in local function does not disappear? (insert function for linked list)

Tags: c, linked-list

I wonder why newNode in this function does not disappear?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>

typedef struct node {
    float hs;
    float sm;
    struct node *next;  
}Node;

Node* InsertNode(Node* head, int index, float hs, float sm){
    if(index < 0) return NULL;

    int currIndex = 1;
    Node* currNode = head;
    while (currNode && index > currIndex) {
        currNode = currNode->next;
        currIndex++;
    }

    if (index > 0 && currNode == NULL) return NULL;

    Node* newNode = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(Node));
    newNode->hs = hs;
    newNode->sm = sm;

    if(index == 0){
        newNode->next = head;
        head = newNode;
    }

    else {
        newNode->next = currNode->next;
        currNode->next = newNode;
    }

    return head;
}

void Display(Node* head) {
    Node* currNode = head;
    while(currNode != NULL){
        printf("(%.2f, %.2f ) ", currNode->hs, currNode->sm);
        currNode = currNode->next;
    }
}

int main(){
    Node* poly1 = NULL;
    Node* poly2 = NULL;
    poly1 = InsertNode(poly1, 0, 5, 4);
    poly1 = InsertNode(poly1, 1, 6, 3);
    poly1 = InsertNode(poly1, 2, 7, 0);
    Display(poly1);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to code a function for inserting an element. I know that local variables will disappear after called-function end but it's still work?
Please help me solve this problem.

Comment: I'm not sure I see the problem you're having... What behavior did you expect, and what behavior do you really see? Also please take some time to read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Why would you want it to disappear if it's the purpose of the `InsertNode()` function?!

Answer (score 0):

when you call -> `poly1 = InsertNode(poly1, 1, 6, 3);`, `poly1` is already head and `head->next` is **NULL**, hence in these lines:

```
Node* currNode = head;
while (currNode && index > currIndex) {
    currNode = currNode->next;
    currIndex++;
}
```

You are making `currNode` point to **NULL** which later results into:

```
if (index > 0 && currNode == NULL) return NULL;
```